# Android: How to load local zip-compressed audio files in WebView

Tags: android

I created a WebView on Android, which is used to load HTML like the following one:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="zip://resource?fileName=apple.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

`apple.wav` is stored in a local zip file. What I want is, when the user clicks the "play" button on the audio component, WebView will try to load the wav audio from the zip file. Currently what I have tried is creating a local WebViewClient, as follows.

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("zip://resource")) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            String fileName = uri.getQueryParameter("fileName");
            byte[] resourceContents = getResource(fileName);
            WebResourceResponse webResourceResponse = new WebResourceResponse("audio/wav",
                    "UTF-8", new ByteArrayInputStream(resourceContents));
            Map<String, String> responseHeaders = new HashMap<>();

            responseHeaders.put("Content-Type", "audio/wav");
            webResourceResponse.setResponseHeaders(responseHeaders);
            return webResourceResponse;
        } else {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }
    }
    private byte[] getResource(String resourceName) {
        // read the audio contents from the pre-determined zip file
    }
}
```

Then assign it to WebView.

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

But it didn't work. When I clicked on the "play" button, nothing happened. I've been searching on the Internet for a long time, the only relevant question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796550/audio-not-working-in-android-webview-using-shouldinterceptrequest), yet the answer to that question is not elegant, which involves modifying HTML and writing audio files to sdcard.

Why didn't my code work? Is there an elegant way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem using WebInterface, it's not an elegant solution, either, audio files have to be written onto the disk before being played. But it worked.

This is the HTML that I use:

```
<button onclick='Audio.playAudio()' />
```

Create a WebInterface:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PlayAudioWebInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void playAudio() {
        try {
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            FileInputStream fis = getFileInputStream();
            mp.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
            fis.close();
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.debug("Couldn't play audio");
        }
    }
    private FileInputStream getFileInputStream() throws IOException {
        File resourceFile = new File("/data/data/com.example/files/test.wav");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(resourceFile));
        bos.write(extractWAVContents());
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        return new FileInputStream(resourceFile);
    }
    private byte[] extractWAVContents() {
        // extract wav from zip
    }
}
```

Assign it to the WebView

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new PlayAudioWebInterface(), "Audio");
```